# ItextPdf throws IllegalArgumentException while converting tiled tiff into pdf

Tags: itext

I am trying to convert a tiled multipage tiff into pdf using #itextpdf version 5.4.1. But itextPdf throws IllegalArgumentException while processing such tiffs. Do ItextPdf support conversion of tiled tiff? If not, what alternative way can be used for such conversion?

Comment: Try again with iText 5.5.13 and share your tiff.

Comment: Without you sharing the tiff in question it's difficult to give a satisfying answer, especially because tiff is only vaguely specified (there is a specification but a certain amount of deviation from the specification is more common than not).

Comment: Hi @AmedeeVanGasse. Thanks for a quick reply. You can find the tiff on the specified path : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z2rJGBZLlIFlxyR-fwBs5kMeHOth3ADH

Comment: Hi @mkl , any update on this?

Comment: Hi @AmedeeVanGasse, I tried with 5.5.13 version also, but getting the same exception.

Comment: I am not going to take time to look at your file. Please do not tag me. I will not post any further comments. I am not a developer and I don't know the ins and outs of the tiff code. iText 5 is going to end of life soon. If this is critical for your business, then I recommend that you contact iText directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the details of that `IllegalArgumentException` you'll see that it's message is **Tiles are not supported.** Thus,

> Do ItextPdf support conversion of tiled tiff?

No, iText does not support conversion of tiled tiff images to PDF images.

> what alternative way can be used for such conversion?

Preprocess the image and transform it, either into a non-tiled tiff or into a different bitmap format altogether, before using it in iText.